Why my fulltext search fails to return values?
I am experementing upon fulltext search using the following example:

CREATE TABLE `search_demo` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=49 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO search_demo (name) VALUES
     ('Quentin Donnelly'),
     ('Camryn Gleichner'),
     ('Mrs. Baby Bogan'),
     ('Prof. Aric Schamberger'),
     ('Prof. William Kris'),
     ('Emile Denesik DDS'),
     ('Deja McKenzie'),
     ('Ralph Bruen I'),
     ('Clare Oberbrunner'),
     ('Lew Kshlerin'),
     ('Dr. Hank Boehm I'),
     ('Dana Lindgren'),
     ('Mozell Mayer'),
     ('Zander Stracke'),
     ('Alba Metz I'),
     ('Franco Considine II'),
     ('Ms. Maya Bartell'),
     ('Dr. Dejon Kulas'),
     ('Gussie Hermann'),
     ('Marlin Dare'),
     ('Mr. Burley McKenzie II'),
     ('Hugh Ernser MD'),
     ('Nona Strosin'),
     ('Jermaine Friesen'),
     ('Austen Smith'),
     ('Prof. Arjun VonRueden'),
     ('Eryn Haag'),
     ('Zander Hayes'),
     ('Shanon Hermiston'),
     ('Tyshawn Morissette'),
     ('Izaiah Koelpin'),
     ('Norwood Schinner'),
     ('Anita White PhD'),
     ('Tressa Mann MD'),
     ('Wyman Medhurst IV'),
     ('Mr. Cale Hartmann'),
     ('Dr. Thurman Schmidt'),
     ('Kallie Auer'),
     ('Ms. Connie Jenkins II'),
     ('Dr. Jaydon Larkin'),
     ('Alfonso Lubowitz III'),
     ('Orion Funk'),
     ('Gunner Orn'),
     ('Kacie Price'),
     ('Reta Johnston'),
     ('Αποκάλυψη Τώρα'),
     ('Νιτρογλυκερινη'),
     ('Λαλαλαλα');
     
     select * from search_demo WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('an' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

But the latter query:
select * from search_demo WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('an' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Seem not to return results whatsoever. Do you know why?
This also has been tested both in mysql 8.* and mariadb 10.* .

I suspect it's because "an" is a stop word and is therefore ignored.

MySQL documents its stopwords here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html. MariaDB documents its stopwords here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-text-index-stopwords/. Both of them include "an".

Besides, that, both MySQL and MariaDB don't index very short words by default. This is configurable, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length or https://mariadb.com/docs/server/sql/features/indexes/enterprise-server/fulltext/#Excluded_Words_with_Full-text_Search_and_InnoDB
